# How can I make that one button click event will actl ike a switch for 3 cases?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Button click event executes this method:

```
public void Console(List<Keys> keys)
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 1;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

            DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.NormalOperation);
            DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays);
            DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Dontdisplayoverlays);
        }
```

I want the first click to only call this:

```
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.NormalOperation);
```

Second click should only call this:

```
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays);
```

And third click should only call this line:

```
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Dontdisplayoverlays);
```

And if I make a fourth click it should start again from the first call. The order is always:

```
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.NormalOperation);
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays);
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Dontdisplayoverlays);
```

So fourth click should call this line:

```
DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.NormalOperation);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a counter. Define a private int global variable in your class.

```
private int count = 0 ;
```

Edit your method like this:

```
    public void Console(List<Keys> keys)
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            // first condition
            count++;
        }
        else if(count == 1)
        {
            // second condition
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            // third condition
        }
    }
```

Also you can use the switch case statement instead of nested if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just create field like "int command = 0" that can be 0, 1 or 2.

```
public void Console(List<Keys> keys)
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 1;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

            if(command == 0)
                DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.NormalOperation);
            if(command == 1)
                DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays);
            if(command == 2)
                DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Dontdisplayoverlays);
            /* here can be switch instead of if */
            command++;
            command = command % 3;
        }
```